# How to make typescript transformer

Tags: typescript, babeljs, transpiler, typescript-compiler-api

I'm new to typescript transformer though I’ve used compiler api once, and I'm interested to extend it from just curiosity.

I want to define `?` to be omitted key if the value is undefined and transpile an example

```
var args = { a: undefined, b: undefined, c: 'foo'}
const x = {
    a: args.a,
    b?: args.b,
    c?: args.c
}
```

to

```
var args = { a: undefined, b: undefined, c: 'foo'}
var omitKeyIfUndefined = ['b', 'c']
var x = omitIfUndefined.reduce(function(r, key) {
   if(args[key] === undefined && key in omitIfUndefined) {
     delete r[key]
   }
   return r
}, args)
```

and the result value, x should be

```
{
    a: undefined,
    c: 'foo'    
}
```

How should do I define new AST node `?` in my case, and add transpile-rules?

Comment: Why do you need a transformer and not a utility function?

Comment: Just interest and I wish I would write code like that if possible. I know the way to add babel transformer to new rules to transpile like  [this artical](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2015/09/13/lets-create-a-babel-plugin/) but I don't find articles to extend  diagnostic system and   add ast node to it  of typescript. For prisma users, where condition object value has key with undefined value causes an error. It also looks smarter than function because we can know what value may be omitted  from code.

Comment: As I know, google firestore also causes error if object has key with undefined value, so I always using  spread operator or  preserved delete function it can look ugly to need some conditions.